# Summary table of three variables

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>  ID       HS        REP      YEAR
> 0001      A          a       2015
> 0001      B          a       2015 
> 0001      B          c       2015
> 0001      B          d       2015
> 0002      A          f       2015
> 0002      A          g       2015
> 0002      B          a       2015
> ```
>
> ......   ....      .....     .....

I would like to get the count of "rep" per "HS" (for each HS) and also the count of "Ids" per "REP" for each "HS" (no matter if the same ID appears in more than two HS and hence it will be recorded two times). Desired output:

> ```
>    Year     HS   REP  TotIDs
>    2015     A     3     2    
>    2015     B     4     2
> ```

It means: HS "A" has 3 REPs and 2 IDs found (overall without distinguish by REP) corresponding to HS "A". The same for "B".
I need also some summary statistics like the mean, median etc. I there a way to do this with proc means or univariate or freq (maybe?) in one shot?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not clear the <year> column role, you don't mention it in your example

Comment: It looks You would like to caluclate count of REP group by HS, but first  distinct ID, HS and then calculate count of ID group by HS thats right ?

Comment: I would be surprised if someone can do it with `proc means` or `proc univariate` or `proc freq` in one shot, because you asking for counting distinguish values, I don't think there is such an option in these procs.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a little more versatile when you want distinct value counting within a group.
SQL does **not** have an aggregate function for `mode` statistic.

If the grouping is what appears to be `year, hs` the following is an example:

```
data have; input
ID   HS $ REP $ YEAR x;
id2=id;
datalines;
0001  A     a   2015 12
0001  B     a   2015 2
0001  B     c   2015 3
0001  B     d   2015 5
0002  A     f   2015 13
0002  A     g   2015 14
0002  B     a   2015 6
;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    year
  , hs
  , count(*) as rep
  , count(distinct id) as id_n_unq
  , sum (x) as x_sum
  , mean (x) as x_mean
  , median (x) as x_median
/*  , mode(x) as x_mode -- SQL does not have aggregate function for mode*/
  from have
  group year, hs
  ;
```

[image]